# Evaluating the beta function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to evaluate $B(\frac{7}{3},\frac{2}{3})$. I've considered all the relations in my notes and on the wiki but I always get an incalculable expression such as $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$. The answer in my book gives the expression $\frac{2 \pi \sqrt{3}}{27}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: I only calculated $B(7/3,4/3)$ but can't $B(7/3,2/3)$

Comment: @Mike: Use the fact that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ in order to rewrite $\Gamma(7/3)$ in terms of $\Gamma(1/3)$. *Then* apply the reflection formula.

Comment: OK, I solved it. Thank you very much for your help.